# groupBy on List as LinkedHashMap instead of Map

Tags: scala, list, sorting, hashmap

I am processing XML using scala, and I am converting the XML into my own data structures. Currently, I am using plain `Map` instances to hold (sub-)elements, however, the order of elements from the XML gets lost this way, and I cannot reproduce the original XML.

Therefore, I want to use `LinkedHashMap` instances instead of `Map`, however I am using `groupBy` on the list of nodes, which creates a `Map`:

For example:

```
  def parse(n:Node): Unit = 
  {
    val leaves:Map[String, Seq[XmlItem]] =
      n.child
        .filter(node => { ... })
        .groupBy(_.label)
        .map((tuple:Tuple2[String, Seq[Node]]) =>
        {
          val items = tuple._2.map(node =>
          {
            val attributes = ...

            if (node.text.nonEmpty)
              XmlItem(Some(node.text), attributes)
            else
              XmlItem(None, attributes)
          })

          (tuple._1, items)
        })

      ...
   }
```

In this example, I want `leaves` to be of type `LinkedHashMap` to retain the order of `n.child`. How can I achieve this?

Note: I am grouping by label/tagname because elements can occur multiple times, and for each label/tagname, I keep a list of elements in my data structures.

---

**Solution**
As answered by @jwvh I am using `foldLeft` as a substitution for `groupBy`. Also, I decided to go with `LinkedHashMap` instead of `ListMap`.

```
  def parse(n:Node): Unit = 
  {
    val leaves:mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, Seq[XmlItem]] =
      n.child
        .filter(node => { ... })
        .foldLeft(mutable.LinkedHashMap.empty[String, Seq[Node]])((m, sn) =>
        {
          m.update(sn.label, m.getOrElse(sn.label, Seq.empty[Node]) ++ Seq(sn))
          m
        })
        .map((tuple:Tuple2[String, Seq[Node]]) =>
        {
          val items = tuple._2.map(node =>
          {
            val attributes = ...

            if (node.text.nonEmpty)
              XmlItem(Some(node.text), attributes)
            else
              XmlItem(None, attributes)
          })

          (tuple._1, items)
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the rough equivalent to `.groupBy()` in a `ListMap` you could `fold` over your collection. The problem is that `ListMap` preserves the order of elements as they were appended, not as they were encountered.

```
import collection.immutable.ListMap

List('a','b','a','c').foldLeft(ListMap.empty[Char,Seq[Char]]){
  case (lm,c) => lm.updated(c, c +: lm.getOrElse(c, Seq()))
}
//res0: ListMap[Char,Seq[Char]] = ListMap(b -> Seq(b), a -> Seq(a, a), c -> Seq(c))
```

To fix this you can `foldRight` instead of `foldLeft`. The result is the original order of elements as encountered (scanning left to right) but *in reverse*.

```
List('a','b','a','c').foldRight(ListMap.empty[Char,Seq[Char]]){
  case (c,lm) => lm.updated(c, c +: lm.getOrElse(c, Seq()))
}
//res1: ListMap[Char,Seq[Char]] = ListMap(c -> Seq(c), b -> Seq(b), a -> Seq(a, a))
```

This isn't necessarily a bad thing since a `ListMap` is more efficient with `last` and `init` ops, O(1), than it is with `head` and `tail` ops, O(n).

To process the `ListMap` in the original left-to-right order you could `.toList` and `.reverse` it.

```
List('a','b','a','c').foldRight(ListMap.empty[Char,Seq[Char]]){
  case (c,lm) => lm.updated(c, c +: lm.getOrElse(c, Seq()))
}.toList.reverse
//res2: List[(Char, Seq[Char])] = List((a,Seq(a, a)), (b,Seq(b)), (c,Seq(c)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I also came up with `foldLeft` after experimenting. Also, I switched to `LinkedHashMap`. My code now perfectly retains element order and I can re-create the original XML perfectly.
I didn't have to switch to `foldRight` however as you said, it works with `foldLeft` for me.

Answer (score 1):

Purely immutable solution would be quite slow. So I'd go with

```
import collection.mutable.{ArrayBuffer, LinkedHashMap}

implicit class ExtraTraversableOps[A](seq: collection.TraversableOnce[A]) {
  def orderedGroupBy[B](f: A => B): collection.Map[B, collection.Seq[A]] = {
    val map = LinkedHashMap.empty[B, ArrayBuffer[A]]

    for (x <- seq) {
      val key = f(x)
      map.getOrElseUpdate(key, ArrayBuffer.empty) += x
    }

    map
}
```

To use, just change `.groupBy` in your code to `.orderedGroupBy`.

The returned `Map` can't be mutated *using this type* (though it can be cast to `mutable.Map` or to `mutable.LinkedHashMap`), so it's safe enough for most purposes (and you could create a `ListMap` from it at the end if really desired).